# I am getting error as "General Error while saving the Business Component "

Tags: qtp, qtplugin

In QTP while saving a business Component I am getting error as "General Error while saving the Business Component "
Is anyone facing the same issue while storing the scripts? Please let me know if you know the reason behind this..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Problem was that, QTP tries to save the opened Test script when an Business component is run. Either close the qtp and let QC open it or change the settings which will not save the opened test script.

Regards,
Sandeep